# Hadoop Pig: URLDecoder: Illegal hex characters in escape (%) pattern

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I'm using pig to decode clicksteam events and running into an error as when string '(%)' is encountered.

Here is my error message which happens after my STORE statement below:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URLDecoder: Illegal hex characters in escape (%) pattern - For input string: "u2"
at java.net.URLDecoder.decode(URLDecoder.java:192)
```

Here is my code:

```
DEFINE UrlDecode InvokeForString('java.net.URLDecoder.decode', 'String String'); 

decoded_strings = FOREACH c GENERATE session_id, event_id
,LOWER(term) as search_term
,UrlDecode(facets, 'UTF-8') as encoded:chararray
,day;

STORE decoded_strings INTO 'database.table' using org.apache.hive.hcatalog.pig.HCatStorer();
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by before running the UrlDecode, I used the following pig code:

```
REPLACE(facets, 'u2', '') as facets
```